# Python Crash Course: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

New to coding and running through the exercises in Python Crash Course version 2.  One of the exercises involves creating a file called "remember_me.py" and as far as I can tell, I'm entering the code as it exists in the book almost verbatim, but getting an error:

```
"""Exercise for Python Crash Course."""
import json

#Load the username, if it has been stored previously.
#Otherwise, prompt for the username and store it.
filename = 'username.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        username = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    username = input("What is your name?\n")
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(username, f)
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username}!")
else:
    print(f"Welcome back, {username}!")
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get the following traceback (I replaced the username with "me" here):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\python_work\remember_me.py", line 9, in <module>
    username = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I've tried just starting from scratch and re-typing, but apparently I'm making the same error!

Comment: What's in `username.json`?  Empty files are not valid json, and will lead to this error.

Comment: The code assumes that the `username.json` file doesn't exist the first time you run the script. It creates it, and then uses it the next time.

Comment: `json.load(f.read())` ?

Comment: I've tried it both with an existing file called "username.json" and without one, FWIW, same error either way.  @Barmar is correct in that, in the context of the chapter, the intention of the program is to assume the file doesn't exist, then create it for the next use.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. Is this happening the first time you run the script when the file doesn't exist, or when you come back?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like an error that comes from a completely empty username.json file. The file exists, otherwise you'd be getting the FileNotFoundError, which is handled. Delete the file username.json, and run the program again. Now open username.json, what do you see?

Comment: @japhyr That's what's going on, thanks!  When I was testing the code for errors without user input, it was creating a blank json file.  I'm working from another machine atm, but I'm 90 percent sure that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

filename = 'username.json'

try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        username = json.load(f)

except FileNotFoundError:
    username = input("What is your name? ")
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(username, f)
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username}!")
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:   # This error is for when the json file is EMPTY.
    username = input("What is your name? ")
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(username, f)
        print(f"We'll remember you when you come back, {username}!")
else:
    print(f"Welcome back, {username}!")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_stored_number():
    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            username = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    **except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        return None**
    else:
        return username
number()
```

Solve this problem adding except for blank file username.json